# React-Native Code in Visual Studio Code Error

Tags: react-native

I am new to react and react native. I created a brand new project and open the folder in visual studio code. I saw the App.js file got the error message. It complained that the aliases can only be use in .ts file. Can anybody help

Comment: You should just be able to delete the things red underlined in the app.js and everything will be fine. Those should be above the declaration of the class if I remember correctly.

Comment: It would be helpful to include the code from your App.js file where you are seeing the error.